# Adding a new row to a pandas data frame when columns have different data type?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 2-column pandas data frame, initialized with `df = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ["A", "B"])`. Column A needs to be of type `float`, and column B is of type `datetime.datetime`. I need to add my first values to it (i.e. new rows), but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I can't do `new_row = [x, y]` then append it since `x` and `y` are not of the same type. How should I go about adding these rows? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import rand
```

Option 1 - make new row as a `DF` and append to previous:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ["A", "B"])
T=pd.datetime(2000,1,1)
df2=pd.DataFrame( columns = ["A", "B"],data=[[rand(),T]])
df=df.append(df2)
```

Or, Option 2 - create empty `DF` and then index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5), columns = ["A", "B"])
T=pd.datetime(2000,1,1)
df.iloc[0,:]=[rand(),T]
```